# Making a field in formio calculated from other fields

Tags: formbuilder, angular2-formbuilder, angular-formbuilder, formio, flutter-form-builder

Please I am using formio to create a form, within the form two fields (currency) are to be added and a total is to be generated in a field called total.

I have tried adding this custom javascript code in the calculated value section to the total field
`value= data.value1 + data.value2;`
I also tried `value = parseInt(data.value1) + parseInt(data.value2);`

Comment: Please try to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (you can read how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this issue before. For some reason, setting the value does not display it in the field itself. What worked for me was using `calculateValue` by editing the JSON for the field. To do this:

1. Click on the Edit JSON button for the field.
2. Add the following code to add the values from the previous fields, where `num1` and `num2` are your unique keys:

```
  "calculateValue": {
    "+": [
      {
        "var": "data.num1"
      },
      {
        "var": "data.num2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

3. The field should display the calculated value.

References:

https://jsonlogic.com/

https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/examples/calculated.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I was also able to make it work using this